# return xml parameters in a mysql field

Tags: php, mysql, sql, xml

This is my DB

```
table name: table_item
id
name
param
```

In The param feild has some "xml parameters" data for example:

```
{"model":"large","color":"red","number":"1000",}
```

I could return name by this code:

```
select id,name FROM table_item
```

and print like this in php

```
foreach($rows as $row)
$name= $row->name;
```

now how can I return parameters?
for example I want to have something like this

```
foreach($rows as $row)
{
   $model= $row->param->model;
   $color= $row->param->color;
}
```

I'm using php/mysql.

or sth this:

```
select id,name FROM table_item
where param->color="red" or param->color="yellow"
```

Comment: You gotta parse it in your foreach loop with php.

Comment: IS there not any way? because for example I wana SELECT those article that color=red

Comment: That's it? just select by color?

Comment: I edited my question with an example (last example)

Answer (score 0):

create an additional table for a name / value pair and link it to your first table with `item_id`

```
table: param
id   p_name  value    item_id
---------------------------------
1    model   large    1
2    color   red      1
3    number  1000     1
```

change your original table:

```
table: item
id   name
------------------------
1    round neck cotton t-shirt
```

then you can:

```
SELECT item.id, item.name, param.p_name, param.value FROM item 
LEFT JOIN param ON item.id = item_id
WHERE param.p_name = 'color' AND param.value = 'red';
```

Result:

```
id   name                        p_name   value
-------------------------------------------------
1    round neck cotton t-shirt   color    red
```

see it working: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/07ab2/1

Comment: @Alexander: I see. I imagine performance is better with two tables, though, specially with large amounts of data.

Comment: That's an intersting thought, but I couldn't find any articles to prove this point. Do you saw any?

Comment: @Alexander: Experience from a project, although some years ago. Should be easy to test this with some simple case. Anyway, the solution you suggested takes less changes in existing structure.

Answer (score 0):

You gotta use [`SUBSTRING_INDEX`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index) here.

[**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f7792/12)

```
SELECT id, name
  FROM table_item
 WHERE REPLACE(
          SUBSTRING_INDEX(
              SUBSTRING_INDEX(param, ':', -2), 
                           ',',1), '"','') = 'red'
       OR
       REPLACE(
          SUBSTRING_INDEX(
              SUBSTRING_INDEX(param, ':', -2), 
                           ',',1), '"','') = 'yellow';
```

I also added [`REPLACE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-functions.html#function_replace) - it's not necessary, but you won't have to type double quotes for the color. Same can be done for any other anrgument, as you can see.